# Why are these number input field arrows not hiding?

Tags: html, css

These `input` fields keep showing the arrows, although I keep trying to hide them with `CSS`. I'm not sure if I can sneak in a little thing, but how to do some padding-top on `.total_price` text?

```css
input[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input[type="number"]::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
{
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
}

.total_price {
  padding-top: 2 10px;
}
```

```html
<tbody id="tableRows">
  <tr>
    <td><input type="number" min="0" class="item-table-values" name="numberInputs" value="370"></td>
    <td><input type="number" min="0" class="qty" name="numberInputs" value=""></td>
    <td class="total_price"><strong>$0.00</strong></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have added an extra comma before the brackets, remove it.

```css
input[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input[type="number"]::-webkit-outer-spin-button/*, - shouldn't be here*/
{
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
}

.total_price {
  padding-top: 2 10px;
}
```

```html
<tbody id="tableRows">
  <tr>
    <td><input type="number" min="0" class="item-table-values" name="numberInputs" value="370"></td>
    <td><input type="number" min="0" class="qty" name="numberInputs" value=""></td>
    <td class="total_price"><strong>$0.00</strong></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Whaaaaaaaaat? Thank you!